# Why am getting error with ajax request PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to make a like and dislike vote in `PHP` and `ajax JQuery` .

The problem is, if i clicked like or dislike am getting error in the response.

Let me first show you the table query that i created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `our_productions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`youtube_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`like_num` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
`dislike_num` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

and here my `PHP` snippets by order:

**db.php**

```
<?php
class Tutorial{

    function __construct(){
        //db details
        $db_host = 'localhost';
        $db_user = 'root';
        $db_pass = '123456';
        $db_name = 'productions';

        //connect db
        $con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');

        //select db
        mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);
    }

    function get_rows($id = ''){
        if($id != ''){
            //fetch single row
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM our_productions WHERE id = $id");
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        }else{
            //fetch all rows
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM our_productions");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function insert($data = array()){
        $data_array_num = count($data);
        $columns = "";
        $values = "";
        $i=0;
        foreach($data as $key=>$val){ 
            $i++;
            $sep = ($i == $data_array_num)?"":", ";
            $columns .= $key.$sep;
            $values .= $val.$sep;
        }
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO our_productions ($columns) VALUES ($values)");
        return $insert?TRUE:FALSE;
    }

    function update($data = array(), $conditions = array()){
        $data_array_num = count($data);
        $cols_vals = "";
        $condition_str = "";
        $i=0;
        foreach($data as $key=>$val){
            $i++;
            $sep = ($i == $data_array_num)?'':', ';
            $cols_vals .= $key."='".$val."'".$sep;
        }
        foreach($conditions as $key=>$val){
            $i++;
            $sep = ($i == $data_array_num)?"":" AND ";
            $condition_str .= $key."='".$val."'";
        }

        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE our_productions SET $cols_vals WHERE $condition_str");
        return $update?TRUE:FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

**votes.php**

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
$tutorial = new Tutorial();

if(isset($_POST['id']) != '' && isset($_POST['type']) != ''){
    //previous tutorial data
    $prev_record = $tutorial->get_rows($_POST['id']);
    //previous total likes
    $prev_like = $prev_record['like_num'];
    //previous total dislikes
    $prev_dislike = $prev_record['dislike_num'];

    //calculates the numbers of like or dislike
    if($_POST['type'] == 1){
        $like = ($prev_like + 1);
        $dislike = $prev_dislike;
        $return_count = $like;
    }else{
        $like = $prev_like;
        $dislike = ($prev_dislike + 1);
        $return_count = $dislike;
    }

    //store update data
    $data = array('like_num'=>$like,'dislike_num'=>$dislike,'modified'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    //update condition
    $condition = array('id'=>$_POST['id']);
    //update tutorial like dislike
    $update = $tutorial->update($data,$condition);

    //return like or dislike number if update is successful, otherwise return error
    echo $update?$return_count:'err';
}
?>
```

and finally the **index.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("db.php");
    $tutorial = new Tutorial();
    $trows = $tutorial->get_rows();
?>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function voting(id,type,target){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'votes.php',
        data:'id='+id+'&type='+type,
        success:function(msg){
            if(msg == 'err'){
                alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
            }else{
                $('#'+target).html(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>

<?php foreach($trows as $trow){ ?>
    <div id="content" class="full-width flush-top flush-bottom">
        <article class="post-2037 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-aerial category-blog tag-4120 tag-aerial tag-dslr tag-film tag-fortyonetwenty tag-highlight tag-production tag-san-diego tag-video tag-videography tag-vulcan-uav">

            <div class="full-width red timestamp">
                <h2 class="month">Jan</h2>
                <h2 class="year">2016</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="full-width">
                <div class="container">
                    <header>
                        <time class="day"><?php echo $trow['id']; ?></time>
                        <h2 class="post-title"><a><?php echo $trow['title']; ?></a></h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="fve-video-wrapper vimeo" style="padding-bottom:56.25%;">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $trow['youtube_url']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </div>

                    <footer class="social-blog">
                        <!-- Like Icon HTML -->
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" onClick="voting(<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>,1,'like_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>')"></span>&nbsp;
                        <!-- Like Counter -->
                        <span class="counter" id="like_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>"><?php echo $trow['like_num']; ?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <!-- Dislike Icon HTML -->
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" onClick="voting(<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>,0,'dislike_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>')"></span>&nbsp;
                        <!-- Dislike Counter -->
                        <span class="counter" id="dislike_count<?php echo $trow['id']; ?>"><?php echo $trow['dislike_num']; ?></span>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Eventually, am getting everything in place, but getting the **err** in response when voting, please any help !!!

Comment: Did you check in DB if votes were recorded?

Comment: yes i checked nothing changed its 0 !!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I could be wrong. But it think you nee to pass the data for your POST request as a JSON object `{'id' : id, 'type': type }`

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and check out what's happening in the network tab when you attempt to trigger the ajax. Check the return code from the ajax script. And check the server logs for errors being generated by the ajax script.

Comment: #Mahmoud Tantawy, am getting the exception in php which is err .

Comment: You're basically returning `mysql_query(...` which is false if the update failed, and that's why you always get the `err` returned. The `mysql_*` methods are all deprecated, so maybe you should start rewriting in PDO. The browser won't help you here, it's a database error.

Comment: i've tried the dictionary but nothing changed, also i triggered the ajax request in the response am getting err !!

Comment: I think your update statement is being constructed inproperly. To troubleshoot have your update method return the sql string,  and echo that at the end of votes.php.

Comment: #dan08, would please explain more !

Comment: Actually just check your logs `tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log` if you are on a typical LAMP stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like

```
$data = array('like_num'=>$like,'dislike_num'=>$dislike,'modified'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

is setting a field named 'modified, but there is no 'modified' in the table definition.

Comment: oh yea dammit, let me give it a shoot :), brb .

Comment: oppppssyyyyyy, i guess you are right dude, it worked, i need to add that wicked column in the table :) , tons tons tons appreciated ;) .